# Text time to numbers

Tags: php, text, time

I have multiple rows with time

```
"42 sec"
"1 min"
"2 h 32 min"
```

Is it possible to convert this to

```
"00:00:42"
"00:01:00"
"02:32:00"
```

with php?

Comment: Is the data you need to convert following a fixed pattern? Because in your third example, `2 h` has a space in between. Is that intentional?

Comment: As far as the fixed pattern, there's a space in `1 min` and not in `32min` too

Comment: @hookedonwinter Sorry. Edited . :)

Comment: no worries. My answer allows 1 space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP's [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is a useful function that can convert a string representation of a time into a unix timestamp. From that we can then convert the time into any format we like.

However, your original time strings aren't in a format that `strtotime()` can handle directly. eg. 'h' must be 'hour'. But we could perhaps replace these before passing to strtotime() if your data is consistent.

Note we attempt to convert the original time relative to 0, not the current time.

```
$rawTimes = array ('42 sec', '1 min', '2 h 32min');
foreach ($rawTimes as $rawTime) {
  // Convert into a format that strtotime() can understand
  $rawTime = str_replace('h','hour',$rawTime);
  echo '"'.$rawTime.'" = "'.gmdate('H:i:s',strtotime($rawTime,0)).'"'."\n";
}
```

Will output:

```
"42 sec" = "00:00:42"
"1 min" = "00:01:00"
"2 hour 32min" = "02:32:00"
```

Note that `strtotime()` understands 'sec', 'second', 'min', 'minute' and 'hour'. And appears to handle space or no space OK eg. '32min' or '32 min' is handled OK.

Comment: Great solution @w3d. I didn't realize you could do the 0 date like that. I was trying to figure out a way to use strtotime(), and was thinking of doing something like `now + 42 seconds - now`. Good one.

Comment: @hookedonwinter - thanks. The 2nd param is for calculating relative dates. You could may be do `strtotime($rawTime)-time()` in this particular instance, but unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution, but it works for your three cases:

```
<?
    $time[] = "42 sec";
    $time[] = "1 min";
    $time[] = "2 h 32min";

    $seconds = '/([\d]{1,})\s?sec/';
    $minutes = '/([\d]{1,})\s?min/';
    $hours = '/([\d]{1,})\s?h/';

    foreach( $time as $t )
    {
        echo '<br />';
        preg_match( $hours, $t, $h );
        $hour = $h[1];
        if( $hour )
        {
            if( strlen( $hour )<2 )
                $hour = '0' . $hour;
        }
        else
            $hour = '00';


        preg_match( $minutes, $t, $m );
        $min = $m[1];
        if( $min )
        {
            if( strlen( $min )<2 )
                $min = '0' . $min;
        }
        else
            $min = '00';

        preg_match( $seconds, $t, $s );
        $sec = $s[1];
        if( $sec )
        {
            if( strlen( $sec )<2 )
                $sec = '0' . $sec;
        }
        else
            $sec = '00';

        echo $hour . ':' . $min . ':' . $sec;

    }
?>
```

Outputs:

```
00:00:42
00:01:00
02:32:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's a better solution, but that one works.

```
function timetotime($str) {
    $match = null;
    if (preg_match("/(\d+)(\s?)h/", $str, &$match)) {
        $h = $match[1];
        if ($h < 10)
            $result = "0{$h}:";
        else
            $result = "{$h}:";
    } else 
        $result = "00:";

    if (preg_match("/(\d+)(\s?)min/", $str, &$match)) {
        $h = $match[1];
        if ($h < 10)
            $result .= "0{$h}:";
        else
            $result .= "{$h}:";
    } else
        $result .= "00:";

    if (preg_match("/(\d+)(\s?)sec/", $str, &$match)) {
        $h = $match[1];
        if ($h < 10)
            $result .= "0{$h}";
        else
            $result .= "{$h}";
    } else
        $result .= "00";

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
<?php
$dates = array("42 sec", "1 min", "2 hour 32 min"); // normalise last item

foreach($dates as $d)
    printf("%5s - %s\n", $d, nSecs($d));

function nSecs($date)
{
    $t = strtotime("+1 day $date");
    return $t - strtotime("+1 day");
}
?>
```

If you can normalise the `h => hour`, it's not so bad.

Comment: `echo strtotime( "42 sec" );` returns `1280680057`, which probably isn't incredibly helpful to the OP.

Comment: `
<?php
$dates = array("42 sec", "1 min", "2 hour 32 min"); // normalise last item
foreach ($dates as $d) printf("%5s - %s\n", $d, nSecs($d));
function nSecs($date) {
 $t = strtotime("+1 day $date");
 return $t - strtotime("+1 day");
}
?>
`
If you can normalise the h => hour it's not so bad.

Comment: for sure. Just gotta put that in the answer, not link the guy to a function doc :)